# Symfony FOSUserBundle invalid credentials - login redirect itself

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working with fos user bundle , the very basic installation of [Symfony's website](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

Security.yml

```
  security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path: /home
            logout: 
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: /login
            anonymous: true
    access_control:
            - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ,requires_channel: https }
            - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,requires_channel: https }
            - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
            - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/details, role: ROLE_USER }
            - { path: ^/prestataire, role: ROLE_USER }
            - { path: ^/recherche, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Config.yml added :

```
fos_user: 
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel' 
firewall_name: main 
user_class: Memo\DevisBundle\Entity\User
resetting:
    email:
        from_email:
            address:        test@gmail.fr
            sender_name:    Confirmation mail
registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled: true  
        from_email:
            address:        test@gmail.fr
            sender_name:    Confirmation mail
```

The user class is very standard.

**What i tried ?**

- Clearing the cache (dev and prod modes).
- coping the bundle from the github
- Resetting password works fine, and after resetting it will connect automatically (thats the i'm doing to connect).

My website is already mounted in **OVH**. So i can't use commands.

The error that i'm getting :

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials.
```

**I dont need to translate the bad credentials. I need to resolve the issue.**

Please i need help !

Comment: That's an authentication issue. Did you use the `/register` route to register the user you are trying to login as? Also did you check the database to see if the user is created in your `User` table?

Comment: yes all of that is fine ! i registered a user, u tried the login with him , and every thing was fine in the database even the "enabled" attribute , but the same issue

Comment: Also did the command: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` get run. If not, then you need to figure out how to run it first. And if so, do you have a `fos_user` table that is populated. If you don't answer my question, i won't help you anymore.

Comment: actually how can i update the shema of the db if my website is mounted in OVH ? how can i run the command ?

Comment: Is `OVH` Cloud computing? maybe [this link has the answer](https://www.ovh.com/us/g1260.how_to_log_in_to_your_vps). Using PuTTY.

Comment: you can update the DB schema in your local machine, after that import your DB in a production environment.